# What could be a good example for: $\frac{\rm d}{{\rm d}x}\sum_{n\in\mathbb N}f_n(x)\neq \sum_{n\in\mathbb N}\frac{\rm d}{{\rm d}x}f_n(x)$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series

I need an power series example for which $$\frac{\rm d}{{\rm d}x}\sum_{n\in\mathbb N}f_n(x)\neq \sum_{n\in\mathbb N}\frac{\rm d}{{\rm d}x}f_n(x)$$

here $f_n(x)$ is differentiable for all $n \in \Bbb N$

Comment: Would you consider it enough to give an example where the right-hand side exists but the left-hand side doesn't?

Comment: Do you need a power series, or just series?

Comment: @Max Freiburghaus it is ok to be one side does not exists

Comment: @N. S. how do we consider this case for a series?(how do we differentiate a non-power series?)

Comment: On second thoughts, the example I thought of doesn't do that because neither exists...

Comment: Power series behaves very nicely in the sense that if it converges on an open interval then it is termwise-differentiable on that interval.

Comment: @BadEnglish If $f_n$ are differentiable on an interval, $\sum f_n$ converges pointwise to $f$ and $\sum_n f'_n$ are uniformly convergent to $g$ on the interval, then $f$ is diferentiable and $f'=g$. So any counterexample needs $\sum_n f_n'$ not to converge uniformly. For power series, you get for free uniform convergence inside the OPEN interval of convergence, so you need to look at the end points. In general, i.e. not for power series, the problem is also pretty well understood.

Answer (score 1):

Take $$-\ln(1+x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^nx^n}{n}$$
at $x=1$.

$$\left.\frac{d}{dx}\right|_{x=1}\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^nx^n}{n}\right)=-\frac{1}{2},$$
but $$\left(\left.\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{d}{dx}\frac{(-1)^n}{n}x^n\right)\right|_{x=1}$$
doesn't exist.

Comment: Could the downvoter explain ?

Comment: I didn't downvote but I might object that the power series for $-ln(1+x)$ is not defined in a *neighbourhood* of $x=1$ and therefore your differentiation is only one-sided.

Comment: I think if we put $x\in (-1, 1)$ value, it is always L.H.S=R.H.S

Comment: @BadEnglish: yes of course ! The question was for a fix $x$ do we always have the equality. It's just an example were it doesn't work...

Comment: @MaxFreiburghaus: Let say that it's an example were the left derivative are not the same... It's enough to say that the more general case is wrong.

Comment: The problem is that the left derivative is not a derivative, in spite of its name. left differentiability is *more* general than differentiability.